# Looking for a google.colab substitute in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm a noob at coding and I'm trying to learn Python by my own.
I know only the basic of the basics, but I got an idea for a simple program and I decided to try making it. As I said, the idea is simple:
its starts with a form, then the program get the answers and categorizes them giving me the results.

```
p1 = int(input('1: Você se considera lindo? '))
p2 = int(input('2: Você sse considera feio? '))
p3 = int(input('3: Você se considera legal? '))
p4 = int(input('4: Você se considera chato? '))
e1 = (p1 + p3) / 2
e2 = (p2 + p4) / 2
if e1 >= 4:
    print('Foi apresentado o esquema 1 com a media: {}'.format(m1))
elif e2 >= 4:
    print('Foi apresentado o esquema 2 com a media: {}'.format(m2))
else:
    print('Não foi apresentado nenhum esquema.')
```

Good, works fine. But I want to use it with google Forms and Sheets.
Ended up in Google Colab and I got this code here that do the trick for me:

```
!pip install --upgrade gspread
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

worksheet = gc.open('Teste YSQ - S3 (respostas)').sheet1

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = worksheet.get_all_values()
print(rows)

# Convert to a DataFrame and render.
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)
```

So,I'm a newbie and now I have questions.

my problem is:

I tried to run it in Pycharm but failed. hehe
Is there any library to substitute google.colab in Pycharm that is possible to use and authenticate the acess like in the code above?

Comment: "I tried to run it in Pycharm but failed." How so? What happened? Did it throw an error? Did it do nothing? Did it behaves differently than expected?

Comment: Oh, first of all, if I run with the "!pip install --upgrade gspread" he pops a syntax error:

"  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MyTestScripts/test.py", line 1
    !pip install --upgrade gspread
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Then, I tried to remove the first line and the message the shows is about the module that pycharm cant find:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MyTestScripts/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.colab import auth
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'"

Thefore I've conclued that this module is not avaiable in pycharm, and I need an other one to use in its place.

Comment: In short, I want the program to ask the user to log in and give it acess to his google drive, so it can open the sheet created by google form and colect tha data. That said, I have no idea on what module I should use inn pycharm.

Comment: The ! escape is for Notebooks. It is not valid in a regular python code file. If you want to install a module in PyCharm, you can either do so via the pop-up on unsatisfied imports, or the preferences.

Comment: Thank you. Also, after some hours of research I found what I need. Its the google login with Oauth2. That way the final user can log in and give acess for the program to read the worksheet.Next step: learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to import the google-colab package for a few months, but now that option appears to be down. You can try to install the oauth plugin and configure google as an option directly in pycharm.